# Where are bios ISR stored and how interrupts are processed?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, bios, interrupt-handling

The interrupts number starts from 0x00 and goes to 0x400, total of 256. My question is that how interrupts are handled and where are interrupt service routine stored of bios? Does the memory locations (0x00 - 0x400) contain pointers to ISR?

[image: Reference image]

Comment: The pointers (interrupt vectors) are stored in the interrupt vector table, from `0000:0000` to `0000:0400` like always.  Where they point is typically to somewhere in the `f000` segment which is where the BIOS ROM is mapped; that's where the actual code for the BIOS's interrupt handlers would live.

Comment: Note that this is only how it works in real mode.  Protected mode works differently and is more complex.  But yes, you are right.